# Is there a way to write a regex on javascript to , break a line when the sentence ends (fullstops)?

Tags: javascript, regex

**Here is my current function**

```
function updateChatContainer(response) {
    
    const chatContainer = document.getElementById('chat-container');
    const titleElement = chatContainer.querySelector('.title h2');
    const ingredientsElement = chatContainer.querySelector('.ingredients h2');
    const instructionsElement = chatContainer.querySelector('.instructions h2');

    const formattedResponse = formatResponse(response);

    titleElement.innerHTML = `<h2>${formattedResponse.title}</h2>  `;
    ingredientsElement.innerHTML = `<h2>Ingredients</h2><p>${formattedResponse.ingredients}</p>`;
    instructionsElement.innerHTML = `<h2>Instructions</h2><p>${formattedResponse.instructions.replace(/(\d+)\.\s/g, '$1. ').replace(/ \./g, '<br>')}</p>`;

    chatContainer.style.display = 'block';


}
function formatResponse(response)
{
    const str = response;
    const Title = "Title:";
    const Ingredients= "Ingredients:"
    const Instructions = "Instructions:";

    const TitleStart = str.indexOf(Title);
    const TitleEnd = TitleStart + Title.length  ;

    const IngredientsStart = str.indexOf(Ingredients);
    const IngredientsEnd = IngredientsStart + Ingredients.length  ;

    const InstructionsStart = str.indexOf(Instructions);
    const InstructionsEnd = InstructionsStart + Instructions.length  ;

    const range1Start = TitleEnd;
    const range1End = str.indexOf(Ingredients);

    const range2Start = IngredientsEnd;
    const range2End = str.indexOf(Instructions);
    
    const range3Start = InstructionsEnd;
    const range3End = str.length;

    let rangeTitle = str.substring(range1Start,range1End);
    let rangeIngredients = str.substring(range2Start,range2End);
    let rangeInstructions = str.substring(range3Start,range3End);
    console.log(rangeTitle);
    console.log("\n");
    console.log(rangeIngredients);
    console.log("\n");
    console.log(rangeInstructions);


    return {
        title: rangeTitle,
        ingredients: rangeIngredients,
        instructions: rangeInstructions
    };
}
```

these codes give something like this

```
Classic Scrambled Eggs
Ingredients
- 2 eggs - 1 tablespoon butter - Salt and pepper (to taste)

Instructions
1.
Crack the eggs into a bowl and beat them until the yolks and whites are well combined.
Season with salt and pepper to taste. 2.
Heat a non-stick skillet over medium-low heat.
Add the butter and allow it to melt and coat the bottom of the skillet. 3.
Pour the beaten eggs into the skillet and let them cook undisturbed for a few seconds until the edges start to set. 4.
Gently stir the eggs with a spatula, pushing them from the edges towards the center, allowing the uncooked parts to come in contact with the hot skillet. 5.
Continue to cook and stir the eggs until they reach your desired level of doneness.
For creamy and soft scrambled eggs, cook for about 2-3 minutes.
If you prefer them more well-done, cook for an additional minute or two. 6.
Once cooked, transfer the scrambled eggs to a plate and serve hot.
Enjoy them with toast, bacon, or any other favorite breakfast sides. Note: If you would like to add a touch of flavor, you can sprinkle some finely chopped garlic or onions while stirring the eggs in step 4.
```

**As you can see , those codes will break a line at numbers .**

i want it to be like this

```
 Classic Scrambled Eggs
- 2 eggs
- 1 tablespoon butter
- Salt and pepper (to taste)
1. Crack the eggs into a bowl and beat them until the yolks and whites are well combined. Season with salt and pepper to taste.
2. Heat a non-stick skillet over medium-low heat. Add the butter and allow it to melt and coat the bottom of the skillet.
3. Pour the beaten eggs into the skillet and let them cook undisturbed for a few seconds until the edges start to set.
4. Gently stir the eggs with a spatula, pushing them from the edges towards the center, allowing the uncooked parts to come in contact with the hot skillet.
5. Continue to cook and stir the eggs until they reach your desired level of doneness. For creamy and soft scrambled eggs, cook for about 2-3 minutes. If you prefer them more well-done, cook for an additional minute or two.
6. Once cooked, transfer the scrambled eggs to a plate and serve hot. Enjoy them with toast, bacon, or any other favorite breakfast sides.
Note: If you would like to add a touch of flavor, you can sprinkle some finely chopped garlic or onions while stirring the eggs in step
4.
```

Is there a reg ex that i can foramt the response correctly ?

Comment: (1) Your question is not clear. (2) The text above *"As you can see"* does not show what you claim, although @Gabriele's edit may have fixed that.  (3) You should show what you expect as the result. (4) What have you tried to get what you want and what did it do?

Comment: I edited the question . can you take a look again

Answer (score 0):

How about this regex:

```
(?<!\d)\.|\s-\s
```

[Demo Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uuJJ22/1)

Js Code:

```
str = str.replaceAll(reg, "\n")
```

```js
const regex = /(?<!\d)\.(?= \d+)|\s?-\s|\.(?= Note)/gm
let str = `Classic Scrambled Eggs
Ingredients
- 2 eggs - 1 tablespoon butter - Salt and pepper (to taste)

Instructions
1.
Crack the eggs into a bowl and beat them until the yolks and whites are well combined.
Season with salt and pepper to taste. 2.
Heat a non-stick skillet over medium-low heat.
Add the butter and allow it to melt and coat the bottom of the skillet. 3.
Pour the beaten eggs into the skillet and let them cook undisturbed for a few seconds until the edges start to set. 4.
Gently stir the eggs with a spatula, pushing them from the edges towards the center, allowing the uncooked parts to come in contact with the hot skillet. 5.
Continue to cook and stir the eggs until they reach your desired level of doneness.
For creamy and soft scrambled eggs, cook for about 2-3 minutes.
If you prefer them more well-done, cook for an additional minute or two. 6.
Once cooked, transfer the scrambled eggs to a plate and serve hot.
Enjoy them with toast, bacon, or any other favorite breakfast sides. Note: If you would like to add a touch of flavor, you can sprinkle some finely chopped garlic or onions while stirring the eggs in step 4.
`
str = str.replaceAll(regex, (match, index) => {
    const matched = match.trim()
    if (matched === '.') {
    // add new line after valid end of line
        return '.\n'
    }
    else {
    // add new line before valid bullet point
        return '\n- '
    }
})

str = str.replace(/ ?\d+\.\n/gm, (match, index) => {
    // remove the new line character after a numbered bullet and add a single space just after the numbered bullet
    return match.slice(0, -1).trim() + ' '
})

str = str.replaceAll(/\d+\.([a-zA-Z0-9\- .\n,]+?)\n(?=\d+\.)/gm, (match) => {
  // get the numbered bullet content and remove any new lines present in the content
    return match.replaceAll('\n', ' ') + '\n'
})

console.log(str)
```